# Does alcohol set off liquid contact indicators?

Tags: pcb, cleaning

I have a MacBook Pro PCB that has lots of yucky, gooey and sticky grime from a spill that thankfully didn't damage the board. I would like to clean the PCB thoroughly, but I fear turning the liquid contact indicators (LCI) red and raising eyebrows at AppleStore in case I take my machine in for paid repairs.

I've read about repair shops using ultrasonic cleaning using water mixed with Branson Ultrasonic Cleaning Solution to clean PCBs, but it is unclear whether it sets off the LCIs. Does it set them off?

I'm considering using a soft brush and denatured alcohol, which is around 90% ethyl with some methyl additives according to MSDS. Do I need to be extra careful to avoid having alcohol contact the LCIs?

Comment: Isn't opening it voiding the warranty anyway?

Comment: This is a bit unclear to me. After a spill, you are not worried about water damage from the spill but are worried about water from the cleaner to clean up the spill? I can only assume that you are referring to cleaning the OUTSIDE of the laptop? Not opening it up and cleaning the board? If that's the case just mist a cloth with alcohol and wipe it down. If the cloth is dry enough it would go anywhere.

I don't think you're supposed to have extended skin contact with methyl alcohol, wood alchol, or denatured alcohol. I seem to remember an MSDS saying to seek medical attention if that happens.

Comment: @Toor, Thank you.  I have a ambigous pronoun in my sentence. I will update the question.

Comment: *I obviously meant to say  "wouldn't go anywhere"

Comment: When a company puts "warranty void if broken or removed" sticker on, they are actually breaking the law.  https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/press-releases/2018/04/ftc-staff-warns-companies-it-illegal-condition-warranty-coverage

Comment: What about smoke detectors? LOL1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alcohols are hygroscopic, meaning they will readily absorb water. It is unlikely the alcohol you have is anhydrous, so I would not advise getting it near the indicators.

I suspect anhydrous alcohol would still change the LCIs.